# How to fill CSS3 columns starting from the end with empty ones at the beginning?

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I want to fill CSS3 columns starting from the end. Is there a way to do this with pure CSS? So if I have for example 4 columns, they should look like this:

empty | empty | empty | content

I tried `direction: rtl;` but it makes only one column at the end, without empty ones at the beginning.

http://jsfiddle.net/bruha/m51oopdm/

Comment: try to add `float:left` to your columns

Comment: Can you post sample code in Jsfiddle

Comment: Please can you provide code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Are you talking about a generic grid system, or about the CSS3 column system (i.e. `column-count`)?

Comment: @Jack I'm talking about CSS3 column system (columns rule)

Comment: so I think there is no selector AFAIK...

Comment: @Govind I have added jsfiddle example

Comment: The columns are only created as the text content fills the space. It's not like divisions which are always present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a pure CSS3 solution.  Wrap your `.cols <div>` inside another `<div>` where you specify `rtl` direction. Set the width of this `rtl <div>` as per your need.

```
<div class = 'rtl'>
    <div class = 'cols'>
        your text here
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:
You also need to specify your number of columns and add `text-align: left;` to `.cols` so that the text aligns correctly inside the columns.

```
.cols {
    column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-width: 30px;
    column-width: 30px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid red;
    column-width: 1px solid red;
    text-align: left;
}
.rtl{
    width: 30%; /* specify this as you like */
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eLxx9ht4/2/

Answer (score 0):

As its not possible to do with Column layout in CSS.
Please refer the W3C standards and its example [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/).

Instead you have to control the columns through width.. means divide the column by div and calc the width out of 100%/no of cols and make first three div as disable.

Hope this should help.